# Query of set time range relative to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I come in to work 6.30am, and need to audit what happened from 5pm when I left to 6.30am this morning. I have used code to search 13.5 hours back from any given time:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY
WHERE TRANSACTION_HISTORY.ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME > (SELECT DATEADD(hour,-13.5,(SELECT MAX (TRANSACTION_HISTORY.ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME) FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY)))
```

Problem is if I run query later, I lose time from the start, eg. If I run query at 7am, I only get results from 5.30pm onwards. Rather than change criteria every day, I wanted to able to search from 6.30am of the current day, back to 5.30pm of the previous day. Can this be done?

Comment: This is using SQL Server syntax so I tagged it SQL Server.

Comment: What version/flavor sql are you running?  You could just set your start date at a certain time...

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't advise using `between` for `datetime`, because the boundary conditions can cause confusion.  I don't think that is the case.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANSACTION_HISTORY th
WHERE th.ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME between cast(cast(getdate() -1 as date) as datetime) + 17.5/24.0
                                    cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + 6.5/24.0;
```

The expression `cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)` is truncating the datetime value to midnight.  As a `datetime`, SQL Server lets you add a number which is understood as a fraction of a day.  Hence, `17.5/24` represents "5:30".  This addition doesn't work for the `date` data type.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that worked great :) now what if I wanted to export the results to Excel, can I include in same same query code? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
    DECLARE @dt datetime
    DECLARE @dt1 datetime
    DECLARE @dt2 datetime

    SET @dt = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101 ), 101)

    SET @dt1 = dateadd(mi, 30, dateadd(hh, 6, @dt))

    SET @dt2 = dateadd(mi, -27*30, @dt1)

    SELECT @dt1 as StartDate, @dt2 as EndDate
```

For additional details what this script does you may check these pages.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I'll try this as well, to get a feel for the options, thanks :)